# Ant Design v4 Card Style boxShadow

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to change the card style:

boxShadow: [0, 8, 24, rgba(208, 216, 243, 0.6)]

---

However, it shows warning as rgba is not defined.

How can I assign styles to boxShadow, it got more properties than other CSS items.

boxShadow got both shadow border and rgba color.

---

Card style={
  width: 360,
  height: 192,
  borderRadius: 16,
  marginRight: 24,
  boxShadow: [0, 8, 24, rgba(208, 216, 243, 0.6)]
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The values of your style props need to be strings and have "px" appended to them. This will work:

```
const cardStyle = { 
    width: "360px", 
    height: "192px", 
    borderRadius: "16px", 
    marginRight: "24px", 
    boxShadow: "5px 8px 24px 5px rgba(208, 216, 243, 0.6)" 
 }
```